# Query to merge results with same values + extra column

Tags: sql, sql-server

So i'm just wondering how I would go about getting the a merged list of two tables, 
one with all the required rows, and the second with extra data to be associated with the first. [image]

So with table 1 and 2 I want to get 3, would this be able to be done as a query?

Comment: What if you have `A 1 1` in `Table1` and `A 1 2 3` (or `A 0 0 1`) in `Table2`? This can never happen ? The relation is on first column (A, B, C) ? You can't have D in Table2 and not D in Table1 ?

Comment: The relation is on the first column yes, there can be different values such as A 0 0 1 but there will be a check to make sure that the first three columns are the same, Table 2 can have D but if it is not in Table 1 it is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if the "empty" value in column coming from table2 can just be NULL, you can do a LEFT JOIN

```
select 
t1.col1, --this is A, B, C
t1.col2, 
t1.col3, 
t2.col4 -- this is the fourth column
from Table1 t1
left join Table2 t2 on t1.Col1 = t2.Col1
```

see [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/98ebf/1)

If you wanna be sure to join only if the 3 columns are the same, just add conditions to the left join

```
on t1.Col1 = t2.Col1 and t1.Col2 = t2.Col2 and t1.Col3 = t2.Col3
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Exists

```
SELECT T1.Column1, T1.Column2, T2.Column3
FROM T1, T2
WHERE T1.Column1 IN
  (SELECT Column1 FROM T1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also try this for the sames results

```
SELECT T1.Column1, T1.Column2, T2.Column3
FROM T1 LEFT JOIN T2 ON T1.Column1 = T2.Column1
```